# IntentRecieverLeakedException, Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver() ? in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying the following sms example from:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android
but I'm getting the following exception if I try to send messages.

```
Exception:
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839): Activity com.micro.MyTest has leaked IntentReceiver com.micro.MyTest$1@435a0c70
that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
unregisterReceiver()?
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.test.SendSMS has leaked
IntentReceiver com.test.SendSMS $1@435a0c70 that was originally
registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:707)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:535)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.registerReceiverInternal(ApplicationContext.java:748)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.registerReceiver(ApplicationContext.java:735)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.registerReceiver(ApplicationContext.java:729)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:278)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at com.micro.MyTest.sendSMS(SendSMS .java:98)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at com.micro.MyTest.onCreate(SendSMS .java:42)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
    02-07 12:38:15.447: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839): Activity com.micro.MyTest has leaked IntentReceiver com.test.MyTest$2@435a13b8
that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
unregisterReceiver()?
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.test.SendSMS has leaked
IntentReceiver com.test.SendSMS $2@435a13b8 that was originally
registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:707)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:535)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.registerReceiverInternal(ApplicationContext.java:748)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.registerReceiver(ApplicationContext.java:735)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.registerReceiver(ApplicationContext.java:729)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:278)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at com.micro.MyTest.sendSMS(SendSMS .java:129)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at com.micro.MyTest.onCreate(SendSMS .java:42)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
    02-07 12:38:15.496: ERROR/ActivityThread(839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The method which sends `sms`:

```
publicvoid sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
  String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
  String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

  PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
  PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

  // When the SMS has been sent, the following line (line 98) throws Exception

  registerReceiver(
    new BroadcastReceiver(){

      public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
          case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
          case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
          case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
          case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
          case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
          }
        }

      }, new IntentFilter(SENT)); 

  // when the SMS has been delivered

  registerReceiver(
    new BroadcastReceiver() {

      public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
          case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break; 
        }
      }
    },new IntentFilter(DELIVERED)); 

  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
  sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI); 

}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

in your activity class, declare these global variables:

```
private BroadcastReceiver sendBroadcastReceiver;
private BroadcastReceiver deliveryBroadcastReceiver;
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
```

override onCreate of your activity and register your receivers:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    deliveryBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };
registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver , new IntentFilter(SENT));
}
```

next, your send sms method is left with only 6 lines of code:

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

lastly, unregister your receivers on stop of your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: sorry i missed that. i've updated my answer. (call register receiver in `onCreate` method)

Comment: it is working... thanks a lot... I've changed few lines of code..registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED)); & SENT, DELIVERED i made it as public and also changed onStop() to onDestroy().

Comment: onStop() or onDestroy() ?

Answer (score 3):

while registering:

```
rec = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
....
}
```

to prevent receiver leak:

```
onStop()
{
super.onStop();
unregisterReciever(rec);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,
can i use same broadcastReceiver name for both Sent & delivered intents? like                                                           
registerReceiver(rec = new BroadcastReceiver()
........
.....
}, new IntentFilter(SENT)); and
registerReceiver(rec = new BroadcastReceiver()
........
.....
}, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

Comment: u're almost close. it is supposed to be like this:
`rec = new BroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("ACTION1");
filter.addAction("ACTION2");
registerReceiver(rec, filter);`

you must ask this as separate question. (also please mark the answer for your original question)

Comment: ok.. can u please tell me where i should do modifications in the above code.

Comment: ok... i've submitted it as a separate answer... hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following two classes to avoid this issue

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsDeliveredReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Log.d("httpmon", "SMS delivered");
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            Log.d("httpmon", "SMS not delivered");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and this one for SMS sent receiver

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Log.d("httpmon", "SMS sent");
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            Log.d("httpmon", "SMS generic failure");
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            Log.d("httpmon", "SMS no service");
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            Log.d("httpmon", "SMS null PDU");
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            Log.d("httpmon", "SMS radio off");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally set receiver in your manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsSentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SMS_SENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".SmsDeliveredReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SMS_DELIVERED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: thanq... can u tell me how tocall these classes from sending function?

Comment: You don't have to call these classes. These classes will receive the broadcasted message. You can receive the intent extras set to these pending intents.


String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

Comment: @VinothkumarArputharaj I implemented your solution and works great. But I've encounter a curious behavior. If I set on a Loop this I keep getting the same ID for all Loops 0,1,2,3,4 The Intent extra always is 0 Any Ideas?

Comment: @eddwinpaz, I can help you if you can share few lines of your code. If you don't find that problem in SO, please add a new question with details and link this.

Comment: @VinothkumarArputharaj The solution its great, Ended up using a unique flag for each intent fixed the issue :D thanks for your support. Any Idea how to delete sms when delivered??

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate & onStop` are not always best places for `register & unregister` when you keep history of activity. You should place `registerReceiver & unregisterReceiver` in `onResume & onPause`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver , new IntentFilter(SENT));
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        // If Receiver not registered
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is very explicit about your problem. You are not calling `unregisterReceiver()` for the `BroadcastReceiver` that you registered with `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: :ok thanks for the reply. if i use [link] (http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/SMSDemo/src/com/varma/samples/smsdemo/MainActivity.java) this example i'm getting the following exception Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { action=SMS_SENT } in com.test.message.Sms$1@437e77d0
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException-----------> here i'm unregistering the receivers then also its coming.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this:

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    switch (getResultCode()) {
...
    unregisterReceiver(this);
}
```

The last thing to do is to unregister Broadcast in onReceive

full:

```
BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    if (Settings.registrarSucesso) {
                        ...
                    }
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    ...
                    }
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    ...
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    ...
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    ...
                    break;
                }
                unregisterReceiver(this);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
private void sendSMS()
{
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
    unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);//add here
        }
    };

    deliveryBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
    unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver);//add here
        }

    };
registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver , new IntentFilter(SENT));
}
```

Comment: What happens if the user opens the `Activity`, but doesn't send an SMS? Also, not all carriers offer delivery reports, and if the device doesn't receive one, the delivery Receiver will never run. It's best to just unregister the Receivers in an `Activity` lifecycle method.

Comment: You're still gonna have same issue if either of those Receivers doesn't run. As I said, the delivery `PendingIntent` in particular may very well not fire, and you'll end up with the exact same problem described in the question.

Comment: Yes. Did you read my comments carefully? You are unregistering the Receivers in the Receivers' own `onReceive()` methods. If either of those methods does not run, the corresponding Receiver will not be unregistered, and will leak. Again, there are some wireless providers who do not offer delivery reports, and in those cases, the delivery Receiver will leak.