# are you missing a call to unregisterreceiver();

Tags: android, exception, wifi

I have create one jar file(library) for android which can start wifi and register broadcast receiver and i have been provided one function so on when activity stops library user can call that function and unregister Receiver.

in library class constructor wifi broadcastReceiver is registered as given below.

```
broadcastReceiver = new WiFiScanReceiver(mWifiManager,mDesiredActRdrSSID);
        mActivity.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        broadcastReceiver.registerActRdrFoundEvent(this);
```

but when i call disconnect functions which contains below code.

```
public void disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
        Log.e(TAG, "Disconnect....***");
        if(broadcastReceiver!= null)
            mActivity.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        broadcastReceiver = null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

But then also it gives error when activity finished.

```
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665): Activity com.example.carparking.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.accesscontrol.WiFiScanReceiver@41287400 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.carparking.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.accesscontrol.WiFiScanReceiver@41287400 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:795)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:596)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1126)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1113)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1107)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:365)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at com.android.accesscontrol.AccessControl.<init>(AccessControl.java:57)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at com.example.carparking.MainActivity.buttonClicked(MainActivity.java:274)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3598)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17150)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4793)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
12-27 08:36:17.756: E/ActivityThread(23665):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can any one help me?
what i am doing wrong? this functions are provided in ".jar" file.

Comment: Did you call disconnect() at onPouse on Activity?

Comment: DO you see this log Log.e(TAG, "Disconnect....***"); ? If not you didnt call this code like Pankaj said.

Comment: @PankajKumar: yup.....

Comment: check these answer its very useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078390/intentrecieverleakedexception-are-you-missing-a-call-to-unregisterreceiver

Comment: Similar question here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078390/intentrecieverleakedexception-are-you-missing-a-call-to-unregisterreceiver

See whether this helps.